# What is needed to get the Windows console to recognize ANSI color sequences, using Python?

Tags: python, windows, ansi-escape

Trying to print colored text on Windows (using Python), the escape sequence prints a left arrow instead of the color.

```
print('\033[1;34mblue\033[1;m')
```

Result:`←[1;34mblue←[1;m`

Is there some terminal setting I need to get this to work? 
Is there another straightforward way in Python to print color so that the same code works for both Windows and Linux?

Comment: Better duplicate target: [Python: How can I make the ANSI escape codes to work also in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12492810/3821804)

Comment: Both of these posts suggest using colorama, which seems to work, so gonna go with with it.