# Python printing color esc codes under win10

Tags: windows, python-2.7, colors

On win10 using python27.

If I run my python script from the command line then the color esc codes display correctly.

If I run the same python script from within windows explorer then the color esc codes no longer work.

How can I configure windows to launch the python27.exe with color esc code support?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How can I make the ANSI escape codes to work also in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492810/python-how-can-i-make-the-ansi-escape-codes-to-work-also-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Simple work around.
Create a batch file to launch the python script.

Instead of running MyPython.py from the win explorer.
Create a batch file MyPython.bat with the text:

```
MyPython.py
```

Running this batch file launches python from within a console and solves the problem of python created console windows not supporting ansi color esc sequences.