# Python, print function ignoring ANSI color commands

Tags: python, colors, ansi-c

I have a similar problem as explained in this post
[ANSI escape code wont work on python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733862/ansi-escape-code-wont-work-on-python-interpreter)

I am using Macbook Pro and Python 3.7.0.  When I give a print command with ANSI commands it prints the characters rather than take effect

```
>>> print ('\033[1;32;48m hello')
[1;32;48m hello
```

I tried with colorama and also initialized it as shown below

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init(convert=True)
```

Not sure what can I do to get it to print in color

Comment: When I type `print ('\033[1;32;48m hello')` into a Python session on a macbook (using iTerm2), I get text in green. Are you using the Terminal app or something else?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your terminal, it's working for me in iterm2 as well

Comment: @khelwood thanks for responding.  I am using the default python shell that opens when I run a program.  Basically I open the file from IDLE.  When I hit run a new window opens which says at the top "Python 3.7.0 Shell"

Comment: This then? [How do I print colored text in IDLE's terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42472958/3890632)

Comment: Thanks @khelwood I tried what the article says and it basically works.  From the article I understand the IDLE can only color text based on its classification like "COMMENT", "STRING", etc and not a general purpose full ANSI escape characters.  I also get an extra numeric output in the result for example: color.write("Yes","STRING"), would color Yes in Green but also add a numeric value. e.g. Yes3.  Anyway, thanks again.  I will have to use something other than IDLE shell if I want all ANSI escape sequences to work