# Unable to print Escape Seqences with Python in Visual Studio (Win 10, Python 3.9, VS 2019)

Tags: python, python-3.9, ansi-escape

**My Issue**

I'm a begginer with Python, and I've been working on code in Visual Studio in which I want to be able use ANSI Escape Sequences to format my output on the terminal console.
I'm using Python 3.9, Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition) and Windows 10 (64-bit).

I originally wanted to be able to move the cursor on the command prompt, like how you are able to do in C++ with the `SetConsoleCursorPosition` function. I also wanted to make my text colored, if possible. People over the internet suggested the use of the `colarama` module, and the Escape Sequences.

I have, however, realized that none of the Escape Sequences appear to work at all in my VS terminal...

**My Attempts**

Here's an example of a suggestion (from [Colorama for Python, Not returning colored print lines on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows)), using the `colorama` module, to color my text:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init(convert=True)

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
```

Code above just prints in white on my VS terminal. I've also verified that I have `colorama` installed properly.

From the same posting, I've also tried:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style, init
init()
from sys import stdout
stdout.write(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "Test" + Style.RESET_ALL + "\n")
```

But it also prints in white.

---

I've also seen the following suggestion, using the `os` module (from [ANSI escape code wont work on python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733862/ansi-escape-code-wont-work-on-python-interpreter)):

```
import os
os.system("echo [31mThis is red[0m")
```

Code above prints the following:

```
[31mThis is red[0m
```

---

As far as I understand, in order to enable the Escape Characters in Python, the call `os.system("")` needs to be performed.

Attempting the following (from [Python: How can I make the ANSI escape codes to work also in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492810/python-how-can-i-make-the-ansi-escape-codes-to-work-also-in-windows)):

```
import os
os.system("")

COLOR = {
    "HEADER": "\033[95m",
    "BLUE": "\033[94m",
    "GREEN": "\033[92m",
    "RED": "\033[91m",
    "ENDC": "\033[0m",
}

print(COLOR["GREEN"], "Testing Green!!", COLOR["ENDC"])
```

Yields the following:

```
←[92m Testing Green!! ←[0m
```

---

As for the moving of the terminal cursor, I've also tried the following (from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474391/is-there-go-up-line-character-opposite-of-n#:~:text=%22%5C033%5BF%22%20%E2%80%93,move%20cursor%20up%20one%20line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474391/is-there-go-up-line-character-opposite-of-n#:%7E:text=%22%5C033%5BF%22%20%E2%80%93,move%20cursor%20up%20one%20line)):

```
import os
os.system("")
print("Previous line")
print("\033[FMy text overwriting the previous line.")
```

Yielding the following:

```
Previous line
←[FMy text overwriting the previous line.
```

As well as trying the following:

```
import os
os.system("")
print("Previous line")
sys.stdout.write("\033[FMy text overwriting the previous line.")
```

Giving the same result.

---

I'm a bit lost at this point, I'm not quite sure why the Escape Characters are not working.
I must be doing something very wrong here...

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't print escape sequences in VSC. Rather try the cmd.