# How can I print colored pyfiglet text in windows cmd

Tags: python, colors, termcolor, figlet

Hello so I am using Python and I want to print out the name of the program with color while using figlet_format so I got it working fine in vscode but when I try to run the file in cmd it prints this:

```
[34m _   _      _ _
| | | | ___| | | ___
| |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \
|  _  |  __/ | | (_) |
|_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/

[0m
```

insted of printing what it prints in vscode:

[image]

So I was wondering if there is a way to print color in cmd while using pyfiglet, this is my code:

```
from termcolor import colored
from pyfiglet import figlet_format

print((colored(figlet_format("Hello"), color="blue")))
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Python: How can I make the ANSI escape codes to work also in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492810/python-how-can-i-make-the-ansi-escape-codes-to-work-also-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you need to install [Colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/).

> Makes ANSI escape character sequences (for producing colored terminal text and cursor positioning) work under MS Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much I just got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this new library **Printy**
Just released version 1.2.0 as a cross-platform library.

Check it out:
[Printy on github](https://github.com/edraobdu/printy)

It is based on flags so you can do stuff like

```py
from printy import printy

# with global flags, this will apply a bold (B) red (r) color and an underline (U) to the whole text
printy("Hello world", "rBU")

# with inline formats, this will apply a dim(D)
#blue (b) to the word 'Hello' and a striked (S)
#yellow (y) to the word 'world', the rest will remain as the predefined format
printy("this is a [bD]Hello@ [yS]world@ text")
```

[image]