# How to clear the current line in the Windows console with Python?

Tags: python, windows, printing, formatting, windows-console

Given an instance here.

For Linux, a down-counter can be implemented as:

```py
# work for Linux
import time
for a in [999,55,1]:
    print(f'\033[K{a}',end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

But it doesn't work for Windows. The key is that the current line cannot be cleared by `print('\033[K'+'Anything', end='\r')`, although it works for Linux.

I know another way using many space symbols:

```py
for a in [999,55,1]:
    print(f'{a}  ',end='\r') # two space symbols
    time.sleep(1)
```

However it is not always perfect, if the list is changed:

```py
for a in [8888888,77,3]:
    print(f'{a}  ',end='\r') # space symbols are not enough
    time.sleep(1)
```

And I don't like the followed space symbols.

How to clear the current line in the Windows console with Python? Avoid using packages for simplicity.

Comment: it's command cls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it in [Python: How can I make the ANSI escape codes to work also in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194390/12128185)

This works well:

```py
# work for Linux & Windows
import time
import platform

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    from ctypes import windll
    windll.kernel32.SetConsoleMode(windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)

for a in [999,55,1]:
    print(f'\033[K{a}',end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically pad spaces depending on the list values in f-strings as `f'{a:<{m}}'`:

```
import time

lst = [9999999,55,1]
m = max(len(str(x)) for x in lst)
for a in lst:
    print(f'{a:<{m}}', end='\r') # m space symbols
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If an iterator is used instead of a list and its elements cannot be gotten immediately (eg. some output when training a big neural network model in each epoch), `m` cannot be gotten before `for`. Do you have a better idea?