# Clearing the line before carriage return

Tags: python

In the following code, I would like to show the progress of two loops with the iteration number for the outer loop and dots for the inner loop.

```
import time
def foo():
    for j in range(0,100):
        if j % 10 == 0:
            print('.', end='', flush=True, sep='')
            time.sleep(0.2)

for i in range(0,100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('\r', i, end='', flush=True, sep='')
        time.sleep(1)
    foo()
```

Although at `i==10` it goes to the beginning of the line, it doesn't remove the dots. So, it actually overwrites the dots. See this figure:

[image]

Is there a way to clean the line and go to the start point with `\r`?

Comment: Add some spaces to overwrite: `print('\r         \r', i, end='', flush=True, sep='')`. Or use [ansi escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences): `print("\r\u001b[0K", end="")`.

Comment: Note: the escape sequences don't work in all terminals - especially online psuedo-terminals. Also, to enable them in Windows console see: [Python: How can I make the ANSI escape codes to work also in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12492810)