# String with ANSI escape codes prints <undefined> character for no apparent reason

Tags: python, terminal, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

I have been building a directory like structure to be printed on the terminal with colours.
However the output has two question mark characters in the middle of the string.

The output is as shown:

[Image of the terminal with the error characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZyOT.png)

And the repr() of the string that originates this output is:

```
'hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mgggggggg\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0miiii\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0mffff\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mttttt\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mttttt\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mdddddddddddddddd\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mppppppppppppppppppppppp\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0mddddddddddddddddddddddd\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0mnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mkkkk\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mmmmmmmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0maaaaaaaaaaaaa\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mttttttttttttttt\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mooooooooooooo\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mdddddddddddddddddddddddddd\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mlllllllllllllllllllllllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m└──\x1b[0mlllllllllllllllllllllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0mpppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m├──\x1b[0mrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m├──\x1b[0mffffffffffffffffffff \x1b[91m<= You are here\x1b[0m\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0meeeeeeeeeeeeee\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m└──\x1b[0moooooo\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mddddddddddddddd\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m├──\x1b[0mjjj\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0meeeeeeeeeeeeee\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m└──\x1b[0mjjjjjj\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mkkkk\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mggggggggggggggggg\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m├──\x1b[0mooo\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mbbbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mhhhhhhhhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m└──\x1b[0mbbbbbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mww\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mtt\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mffffffffffffffffff\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m├──\x1b[0mvvv\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mssss\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mnnnnnnnnnnn\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m└──\x1b[0mmmmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0maa\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mqq\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mggggggggggggggggg\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m├──\x1b[0mnnn\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mgggggggggggggg\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m└──\x1b[0mxxxxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0miiii\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mnnnnnn\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mpppppppppppppppp\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m├──\x1b[0maaa\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0moooo\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mmmmmmmmmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m└──\x1b[0mllllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mhhhhhhhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mkkkkkkkkkkkkk\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m├──\x1b[0muuuuuuuu\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mrrrrrrrrr\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m├──\x1b[0mffff\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m└──\x1b[0meeeeeeeeeeeeee\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mhhhhhhhhhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m├──\x1b[0mnnn\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mlllllllllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mwwww\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m└──\x1b[0mxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0miiiii\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mlllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m└──\x1b[0mxxxxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m├──\x1b[0mtttttttt\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mooooooooooooo\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mjj\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mgg\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mgg\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mcc\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mss\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mvvvvvvvvvvvv\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0maaaaaaaaaaa\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;255;0;153m├──\x1b[0mpppp\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;255;0;153m└──\x1b[0mrrrr\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mlllllllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;255;0;153m└──\x1b[0mttttttttttt\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m└──\x1b[0meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m├──\x1b[0muuuuuuuuuuuuuu\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m└──\x1b[0mdddddd\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0muuuuuuuuuuuuuuu\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m├──\x1b[0maaaaaaaa\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0msssssssssss\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mjjjj\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mqqqq\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mhhhhhhhhhhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mddd\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0maaaa\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mjjjjjj\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mtttttttttttttttttt\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mmmmmmmmmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m└──\x1b[0moooooooooo\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m├──\x1b[0miiiiiiiiiiiiii\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m└──\x1b[0mqqqqqq\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m├──\x1b[0mrrrrrrrr\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mlllllllllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0muuuu\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mhhhhhhhhhhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0miii\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m├──\x1b[0mqqqq\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mvvvvvv\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m├──\x1b[0mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;0;255m└──\x1b[0mppppppppppp\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;0;255m└──\x1b[0mkkkkkkkkkk\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m├──\x1b[0mhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;102;255m└──\x1b[0meeeeee\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mccccccccc\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m├──\x1b[0mjjjjjjjjjjjjjj\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mff\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mcc\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mxx\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m└──\x1b[0muuuuuu\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m├──\x1b[0mmm\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;255m└──\x1b[0mff\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mffffffffffffffff\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m└──\x1b[0miiiiiiiiiiiiiii\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m├──\x1b[0mff\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;0;255;102m└──\x1b[0muuu\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0moooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mbbbb\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mpppp\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m│\x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m└──\x1b[0mllll\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m└──\x1b[0mggggggggggg\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m└──\x1b[0mccccccccccccccccccccccccc\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m├──\x1b[0mnnn\n   \x1b[38;2;255;153;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;203;255;0m \x1b[0m   \x1b[38;2;50;255;0m└──\x1b[0mss\n'
```

When I keep the colour always the same the problem no longer shows, it seems to only happen with RGB colour or TRUECOLOUR.

Comment: Just wondering, are you using an NT system (Windows)? (More specifically, Windows CMD)

Comment: @AnonyMous Yes I am using Windows CMD and Visual Studio Code Terminal, this error happens on both although the VSCode Terminal stops printing as soon as it encounters this problem.

Comment: Ok what terminal are you using in Vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help, but on NT based integrated command lines (aka. Windows CMD), you have to include this before using ANSI escape codes:

```py
import os
if os.name == 'nt':from ctypes import windll;k=windll.kernel32;k.SetConsoleMode(k.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
```

This may not work, as usually a fail won't print `<undefined>`. Maybe try use another terminal, like Powershell if doesn't work.

Comment: That did indeed work for CMD, Thank you. VSCode terminal is the same though, but the program is to be used on the CMD so no problem.
Could you explain in more detail what this line does or why it is needed?

Comment: Honestly, I found it a couple of months ago when I was working on a live-syntax terminal application (like VIM). I think what happens is different terminals use different ANSI esc codes, like CMD uses a different one to say a VSCode Terminal. Some terminals use `\033`, some use `\x1b`, and others use '\e' , and CMD doesn't technically have integrated support. So this is telling it to use the mode with support for the ANSI escape code `\x1b`.  Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492810/python-how-can-i-make-the-ansi-escape-codes-to-work-also-in-windows