# Colored representation of objects in IPython terminal shell

Tags: ipython

If I want to have a colored representation of an objects in a QtConsole or the IPython Notebook, I just have to add the `_repr_html_` method to the objects class.

```py
In [1]: class Test(object):
            def __init__(self, x):
                self.x = x

            def _repr_html_(self):
                return '''<span style="color: green">
                       Test{<span style="color: red">%s</span>}
                       </span>''' % self.x
In [2]: Test(33)
Test{33}
```

This will give me a nice colored representation where `Test{` will be green, `33` red and `}` green again.

Is there a way to do this in the terminal version of the IPython Shell in a cross platform way?

Ideally it would work the same way as the the templates for the [prompt customization](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/shell.html#prompt-customization):

```py
In [1]: class Test(object):
            def __init__(self, x):
                self.x = x

            def _repr_shell_(self):
                return '{color.Green}Test{{color.Red}%s{color.Green}}' % self.x
```

If not, can I somehow import and use the IPython's internal cross-platform coloring system in my own console application? I looked into the IPython codebase, but I haven't found any direct way to use it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TermColors` from IPython.
A minimal example would be:

```py
from IPython.utils.coloransi import TermColors as color
class Test(object):
   def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x
   def __repr__(self):
       return '{0}Test{{{1}{2}{0}}}'.format(color.Green, color.Red, self.x)
```

Comment: Do you know any way I could use the TermColors outside of the IPython environment? On POSIX systems it works fine, but on Windows it just prints out the POSIX escape codes.

Comment: You can check *colorama*, see these SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12492810/2870069 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8358533/2870069

Comment: Yes I know about colorama, but since IPython already does it, I wanted to avoid an extra dependency :)