# Python ASCII plotter

Tags: python, printing, ascii

I'm doing an ascii problem in Python. The goal is to create an image using certain values to create certain images:

The value 0 creates a "-" and moves the cursor to the right for the next variable. 1 creates a "/" and moves the cursor up one row and to the right. 2 creates a "|" and moves the cursor up one row in the same position. 3 creates a "\" and moves the cursor up one row and over to the left one space. 4 creates a "-" and moves the cursor left. 5 creates a "/" and moves the cursor down one row and to the left. 6 creates a "|" and moves the cursor down one row. 7 creates a "\" and moves the cursor down one row and to the right.

However I'm not sure how to print this to make it happen.  My code:

```
file_object = open("input.txt","w")

file_object.write("770000334444")
file_object.write("2255500004666")
file_object.write("002444")

file_object.close()

file_object = open("input.txt","r")


while True:
    c = file_object.read(1)
    if c == "0":
        print("-")
    if c == "1":
        print("/")
    if c == "2":
        print("|")
    if c == "3":
        print("\")
    if c == "4":
        print("-")
    if c == "5":
        print("/")
    if c == "6":
        print("|")
    if c == "7":
        print("\")
```

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on tackling a fun problem.  Because you have an open ended question, I am providing some general information in the hopes it might help you.

The `print` function can print without always going to the next line.  For example, this will print "Hello".

```
print("Hel", end="")
print("lo")
```

You can use the `turtle` module for graphical programs kind of like you want.  You might want to look at the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html)

You can use the `curses` module to draw characters wherever you want.  It is a bit harder to use than `turtle` but does draw characters.  You probably want to start with the [How-To guide](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html#curses-howto).

You can create your own list of lines of characters, fill them in, and print them out.  This is a much harder approach and it doesn't use any libraries.

Have fun!  Keep coding!  Keep notes.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running it in linux, than most terminals understand [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). The relevant codes for this use case:

- `"\033[F"` – move cursor to the beginning of the previous line
- `"\033[A"` – move cursor up one line

Example (Python):

```
print("\033[FMy text overwriting the previous line.")
```

**But** if your'e using windows you will need to use a module that enables ansi escape codes.

You could check [Python module to enable ANSI colors for stdout on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358533/python-module-to-enable-ansi-for-stdout-on-windows) to see if it's useful.

The [colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) module seems to be cross-platform.

You install colorama:

```
pip install colorama
```

and than try using the ANSI escape codes in your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `print("\")` won't work as `'\'` is the escape character so you need to do `print("\\")` instead.

I think it's a mistake to jump into writing code -- to me this is a *data structure* problem.  And the better the data structure, the less code you need to write.  Here's how I might solve this problem using Python turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT_SIZE = 18
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

OPERATORS = [
    ["-",  ( 1,  0)],  # 0 draws "-" and moves cursor to the right
    ["/",  ( 1,  1)],  # 1 draws "/" and moves cursor up one row and to the right
    ["|",  ( 0,  1)],  # 2 draws "|" and moves cursor up one row in the same position
    ["\\", (-1,  1)],  # 3 draws "\" and moves cursor up one row and over to the left
    ["-",  (-1,  0)],  # 4 draws "-" and moves cursor left
    ["/",  (-1, -1)],  # 5 draws "/" and moves cursor down one row and to the left
    ["|",  ( 0, -1)],  # 6 draws "|" and moves cursor down one row
    ["\\", ( 1, -1)],  # 7 draws "\" and moves cursor down one row and to the right
]

def display(turtle, string):
    for digit in string:
        character, (dx, dy) = OPERATORS[int(digit)]
        x, y = turtle.position()
        turtle.write(character, align='center', font=FONT)
        turtle.goto(x + dx * FONT_SIZE, y + dy * FONT_SIZE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.penup()

    display(turtle, "2255500004666")

    screen = Screen()
    screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]