# Issue using pychalk

Tags: python, chalk

When I run

```
import chalk
print(chalk.red("test"))
```

on visual studio code, I am able to get the red "test" output as follows: https://gyazo.com/73473a3fbaf58bbca524232d5952c325

but when i run the code from cmd, the color is no displayed: https://gyazo.com/e75cbafd2485f5fbae1f194bf7d46c8b

what should i use to run the code in a client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Visual Studio Code emulates Linux terminal, while Windows Command line does not.

Linux terminals and Windows command line use different [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) to display output.

Here are some relevant StackOverflow questions:

- [Python module to enable ANSI colors for stdout on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358533/python-module-to-enable-ansi-colors-for-stdout-on-windows)
- [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)
- [Python: How can I make the ANSI escape codes to work also in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492810/python-how-can-i-make-the-ansi-escape-codes-to-work-also-in-windows)

TL;DR: if you want a cross-platform solution, replace `pychalk` with something like `colorama`.

Update: Once you understand the problem, you can also create an issue in the [pychalk Github repository](https://github.com/Throvn/pychalk)