# ANSI escape code ESC[0E doesn't work as expected

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape

I was trying out the example code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60226/1291990).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void drawProgressBar(int, double);

int main() {

    drawProgressBar(30, .25);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    drawProgressBar(30, .50);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    drawProgressBar(30, .75);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    drawProgressBar(30, 1);

    return 0;
}

void drawProgressBar(int len, double percent) {
    std::cout << "\x1B[2K"; // Erase the entire current line.
    std::cout << "\x1B[0E"; // Move to the beginning of the current line.
    std::string progress;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i < static_cast<int>(len * percent)) {
            progress += "=";
        } else {
            progress += " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "[" << progress << "] " << (static_cast<int>(100 * percent)) << "%" << std::flush;
}
```

The expected behavior was a progress bar like so:

```
[=======                       ] 25%
```

which would update three times on the same line, ending up as:

```
[==============================] 100%
```

after 3 seconds.

While each progress bar gets erased as expected, the next progress bar is drawn one line down, not on the same line as I was expecting it to.

The documentation linked in the answer ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)) says that `CSI n E` (`ESC[nE`) where `n` is an integer:

> Moves cursor to beginning of the line n (default 1) lines down.

So I would expect `CSI 0 E` (`ESC[0E`) to move the cursor to the beginning of the current line (the line `0` lines down).

Why doesn't it? Also, how can I achieve the intended behavior?

---

I'm using `Terminal.app` on OS X to run this program.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, try:

```
std::cout << "\r";
```

instead of:

```
std::cout << "\x1B[2K"; // Erase the entire current line.
std::cout << "\x1B[0E"; // Move to the beginning of the current line.
```

This is a **carriage return**, which should reposition the cursor at the beginning of the line.

(By the way, kudos for commenting your code. Love it when people do that on here :) )

Comment: That worked! Thank you. However I would still like to know why `"\x1B[0E"` didn't work.

Comment: @anthropomorphic My best guess is that `1`- the default number of rows to move downwards- is the minimum number possible. After all, there is an ANSI escape code to do what you are doing, but in a simpler way- `\x[F`.

Comment: `[` isn't a valid hex character. Did you mean `\x1B[F`?

Comment: I tried `\1B[F` and the result was the curser relocating to the beginning of the very top line of the terminal.

Comment: Hmm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474391/is-there-go-up-line-character-opposite-of-n says it should have it go to the beginning of the line. Maybe try `\033[0E`? Just playing with the escape sequences, I don't really know if it will work.

Comment: `033 == 0x1B`. `\033[0E` does is equivalent to the original `\x1B[0E`

Comment: Hmm yep, I don't know. I guess I'll stick with my "minimum number theory" :)

Comment: The `0` parameter, unless specifically documented as having an effect, is treated as though missing.  The default for `CSI E` is "1".  The `HPA` (`CSI` *n* `G`) sequence moves within the current row on the screen.